# PHP code wont redirect to the page but shows a blank page

Tags: php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST))
{
    //pre-defined vals
    $to = "salesghana@tallyafrica.com";
    $subject = "PRODUCT AND SERVICE REQUEST";

    //from post form
    $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
    $contact = $_POST['contact'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $company_name = $_POST['company_name'];
    $company_address = $_POST['company_address'];
    $user_type = $_POST['user_type'];
    $pref_service_one = $_POST['pref_service_one'];
    $pref_service_one = $_POST['pref_service_two'];
    $addon_one = $_POST['addon_one'];
    $addon_two = $_POST['addon_two'];
    $comments = $_POST['comments'];

    $message = "NAME: " . $user_name . "\n\n" . "CONTACT: " . $contact . "\n\n" . "EMAIL: " . $email . "\n\n" . "COMPANY NAME: " . $company_name . "\n\n" . "COMPANY ADDRESS: " . $company_address . "\n\n" . "TALLY SOFTWARE: " . $user_type . "\n\n" . "PREFERRED SERVICE ONE: " . $pref_service_one . "\n\n" . "PREFERRED SERVICE TWO: " . $pref_service_two . "\n\n" . "ADDON ONE: " . $addon_one . "\n\n" . "ADDON TWO: " . $addon_two . "\n\n" . "COMMENTS: " . $comments;

    $headers = "<From: noreply@tallyafrica.com>";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    header("Location:http://www.prymage.com/thankyou.html");
}
?>
```

This is my PHP that is sent successfully, but shows a blank white page and doesn't redirect to the header link.

Comment: white screen of death: error checking\display are off, turn them on to see the error. at the top of your php page add: `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); ini_set('html_errors', 0); error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: Check by using Error reporting on. May be you can see error? Also any error log file is there??

Comment: @Khushboo when I use echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $user_name . ", we will contact you shortly."; it displays

Comment: bet a million bucks its header saying ".... headers already sent ..." but without actually displaying errors how would you know

Comment: Put an exit(); on the line After header('location

Comment: @halojoy did not work..

Comment: @rtfm my PHP is not good as you unfortunately for me

Comment: just add the code i told you to add half an hour ago, and you will see the error. you cant fix errors if you cant see them

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I had to guess I would say something is causing output to the browser.  Either a stray echo or print, or whitespace before/after php tags, or an error/exception and errors are suppressed.  The code below will help in the instance that it's the mail function causing output to be generated, but it won't if the output is happening before coming to the `if` statement.

As a bonus, you can do this to return control to the browser faster and continue processing the email after the user has been redirected.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST))
{
    // move header up, add ignore user abort for safety.
    ignore_user_abort( TRUE );
    header("Location:http://www.prymage.com/thankyou.html");

    //pre-defined vals
    $to = "salesghana@tallyafrica.com";
    $subject = "PRODUCT AND SERVICE REQUEST";

    //from post form
    $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
    $contact = $_POST['contact'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $company_name = $_POST['company_name'];
    $company_address = $_POST['company_address'];
    $user_type = $_POST['user_type'];
    $pref_service_one = $_POST['pref_service_one'];
    $pref_service_one = $_POST['pref_service_two'];
    $addon_one = $_POST['addon_one'];
    $addon_two = $_POST['addon_two'];
    $comments = $_POST['comments'];

    $message = "NAME: " . $user_name . "\n\n" . "CONTACT: " . $contact . "\n\n" . "EMAIL: " . $email . "\n\n" . "COMPANY NAME: " . $company_name . "\n\n" . "COMPANY ADDRESS: " . $company_address . "\n\n" . "TALLY SOFTWARE: " . $user_type . "\n\n" . "PREFERRED SERVICE ONE: " . $pref_service_one . "\n\n" . "PREFERRED SERVICE TWO: " . $pref_service_two . "\n\n" . "ADDON ONE: " . $addon_one . "\n\n" . "ADDON TWO: " . $addon_two . "\n\n" . "COMMENTS: " . $comments;

    $headers = "<From: noreply@tallyafrica.com>";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    // added exit for safety in case there is more code below the if statement.
    exit();
}
```

Or the old way but with error reporting:

```
// add in error reporting
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
ini_set('html_errors', 0);
error_reporting(-1);

if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST))
{
    //pre-defined vals
    $to = "salesghana@tallyafrica.com";
    $subject = "PRODUCT AND SERVICE REQUEST";

    //from post form
    $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
    $contact = $_POST['contact'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $company_name = $_POST['company_name'];
    $company_address = $_POST['company_address'];
    $user_type = $_POST['user_type'];
    $pref_service_one = $_POST['pref_service_one'];
    $pref_service_one = $_POST['pref_service_two'];
    $addon_one = $_POST['addon_one'];
    $addon_two = $_POST['addon_two'];
    $comments = $_POST['comments'];

    $message = "NAME: " . $user_name . "\n\n" . "CONTACT: " . $contact . "\n\n" . "EMAIL: " . $email . "\n\n" . "COMPANY NAME: " . $company_name . "\n\n" . "COMPANY ADDRESS: " . $company_address . "\n\n" . "TALLY SOFTWARE: " . $user_type . "\n\n" . "PREFERRED SERVICE ONE: " . $pref_service_one . "\n\n" . "PREFERRED SERVICE TWO: " . $pref_service_two . "\n\n" . "ADDON ONE: " . $addon_one . "\n\n" . "ADDON TWO: " . $addon_two . "\n\n" . "COMMENTS: " . $comments;

    $headers = "<From: noreply@tallyafrica.com>";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    header("Location:http://www.prymage.com/thankyou.html");
    // added exit for safety in case there is more code below the if statement.
    exit();
}
```

Comment: an interesting situation, a thank you from the OP, accepted answer, and a -1.  would be curious to know what the downvote is for.

Comment: sorry@ Tim G sorry but trying to remove but wont remove...how do I fix that?

Comment: @AtoAugustyn just click the up arrow.

Comment: @rtfm agreed, however the likelihood of this block causing an error is slim - the OP would likely see an error in the web page - not just white.  They stated the mail is sent properly so it gets that far without fatal errors.

Comment: @AtoAugustyn you really should dig deeper into the possibility of a suppressed error causing this and add the code rtfm suggested.  I'll edit my answer to show you what they wanted.

Comment: @TimG done that but I guess it is not going to change anytime soon since my reputation is below 15... guess I didnt downvote you

Comment: "the OP would likely see an error in the web page - not just white" unfortunately a lot of people code with error checking of - its called the "white screen of death", a common php issue

Comment: @TimG and much appreciated

Comment: @rtfm will do that thank you but am not a pro like you but will do what you say.